# Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server2012

Tags: c#, sqlgeography

I use the Dbgeography type found in using System.Data.Spatial to do some work on polygons in C#.I save  the polygons as text in sql server 2008 r2 becuase I use Peta Poco for data access (which i really like).Is there anyway I can develop an app in c#  that does not rely on Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server2012 because I can never get it to publish correctly.

Comment: It's not clear how to answer this; since you can save to text, you've got a solution that saves data but doesn't use any CLR features; what situation are you hoping to get to?

Comment: I was hoping to use c# and polygons spatial type data without reliance on Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server2012